# Rearranging PyTorch tensor in a windowed manner

Tags: python, pytorch

So I have a tensor

```
A = torch.tensor([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
```

and I was hoping to rearrange it in sliding windows, that is,

```
f(A) = torch.tensor([[1,2,5,6],[3,4,7,8],[9,10,13,14],[11,12,15,16]])
```

by viewing every tensor in `A` as a 2-by-2 small window, and then arranging the "window"s in a 2-by-2 matrix. This operation is similar to `ArrayFlatten` of Mathematica, but I couldn' find a way to do it in PyTorch. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a neat way to do this off the top of my head, but you can achieve it with a few choice slices and concatenations:

```py
A_ = A.reshape(4,2,2)
torch.cat([torch.cat([*A_[:2]],1), torch.cat([*A_[2:]],1)],0)
```

---

Alternative approaches:

```py
A.unfold(1,2,2).unfold(0,2,2).reshape(*A.shape).index_select(1, torch.LongTensor([0,2,1,3]))
```

```py
torch.cat([*A_],1).reshape(*A.shape).index_select(0, torch.LongTensor([0,2,1,3]))
```

Comment: thanks, I'll stick to alternative approaches as they preserve gradients